# What is the best way of using inheritance in two related classes

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have a pair of base classes, one of which instantiates the other:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class AnimalHome:
    def __init__(self, location):
        self.location = location

    def populate_home(self):
        self.animal1 = Animal(name='Rex')
        self.animal2 = Animal(name='Barney')
```

Now I want a derived AnimalHome class within which I want to use some other class of derived Animal instances:

```
class Cat(Animal):
    # Interesting properties of cats defined here ...

class Cattery(AnimalHome):
    def populate_home(self):
        self.animal1 = Cat(name='Fluffy')
        self.animal2 = Cat(name='Trixie')

    # Interesting properties of Catteries defined here ...
```

I have to repeat essentially the same code in the method `populate_home` to use the `Cat` class instead of the `Animal` class. What is the best way to avoid this repetition?

Should I define a special class method `get_animal_class` on the `AnimalHome` and `Cattery` classes, that simply returns the appropriate animal class:

```
def instantiate_animal(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return Animal(*args, **kwargs)
```

in the `Animal` class, and

```
def instantiate_animal(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return Cat(*args, **kwargs)
```

in the `Cat` class, or is there a better way?

Comment: You can make use of a list.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help: my code is just a simple example to illustrate the problem, I am not actually generating two instances of `Animal` or `Cat` classes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a method to instantiate the class, you can set it as a class variable:

```
class AnimalHome:
    animal_class = None

class Cattery(AnimalHome):
    animal_class = Cat

    # self.animal_class will be Cat in Cattery's methods
```